# Can't recreate SQL Server Express database with Entity Framework Code First and MVC 3 without changing the database name

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-express

When I run the application with the following connection string the database file is created successfully.

```
<add name="ConnString1"
     connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
                       Database=Database1;
                       Integrated Security=SSPI;
                       AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;
                       User Instance=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

If I delete the database file and try to run the application again the database file fails to be created and I get the following inner exceptions:

> The underlying provider failed on Open.

> {"Cannot open database \"Database1\" requested by the login. The login failed.\Database1\nLogin failed for user 'computer\\someuser'."}

If I change *Database=Database1* to *Database=Database2* in the connection string then the database file is created successfully. The problem repeats itself always.

How can I recreate the database file without having to change the database name?

Comment: Have you tried using a file name other than aspnetdb.mdf?  What actions do you take to delete an existing database?

Comment: When I change the name of the database file it gets more bizarre. If I change the name from aspnetdb.mdf to aspnet2.mdf I get the error "Database 'path\aspnetdb.mdf already exists. Choose a different database name. Cannot attach the file path\aspnet2.mdf as database DatabaseName.' where path is the path and DatabaseName is the database name. I am deleting the database files by right clicking them on Visual Studio and deleting them.

Comment: did you find a fix for this?  I'm having a similar problem.  I'm doing the database creation step in xUnit.  The first time it works fine; the second time it fails with `Cannot open database "[my database name]" requested by the login. The login failed.  Login failed for user '[my domain user name]'.`  If I rebuild the project, it works in xUnit again.  But if I try to run the test without rebuilding, it gives the above error.

Comment: I didn't find a fix. I decided to stop using it until it is out of Beta.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I'm using EF4.1 RTW, VS 2010 SP1, SQL Express (With SQL Engine 2008 SP1)... is very bizaree, have to rename the Default Database name everytime to be able to generate the database with same file name. I'll use SQL CE until solved.

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure the directory rights allow you to delete the mdf file and the the login has drop schema/table privileges  directory rights are a common issue with mdf files due the high security placed on these files due to their potentially sensitive nature

Answer (score 0):

I can see this is an older post - hopefully this can help someone in the same predicament.

Using code first, the first time the application runs it builds the db no problems - it knows it doesn't exist because it hasn't previously built it. Code first also takes a hash value of the models used and stores that in the new database - check for a table called EdmMetadata - thats where the hash value is stored. It uses the hash value to subsequently check if the model has changed from build to build, so it knows whether to drop the database and rebuild.

The second time through after you've deleted the database, it looks for the missing database to compare the model hash value, and can't find it because the database is now missing.

My workaround is to add a meaningless field (remembering to delete it after development) to one of the models to force the rebuild, without deleting the database. Alternatively, you could just modify the db hash value to force the rebuild.

This works with the code first application databases - not so sure with the membership database.